# Eclipse CDT Oxygen + DevStyle no build error highlighting

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I recently switch to eclipse CDT(Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)). I also installed the DevStyle Plugin. Since then I don't get error/warning highlighting in the build console. It seems that the error is parsed correctly, because it shows up in the problem window.

Here are some pictures:

Error in Build

[image: Error in Build]

Problem Window

[image: Problem Window]

Settings

[image: Settings]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the problem. Devstyle used black color in default for highlighting warnings and errors. With the new settings it is working.

[console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh3cr.png)